# How to back transform the foretasted values from Prophet algorithm?

Tags: r, time-series, data-transformation

i have log transformed the actual and fed the data into forecasting model(Prophet) and i have the forecast in scaled to log format. I would like to transform them back to normal values. Should taking exp should be enough? i have gone through make links , couldn't get a satisfying answer.

Thanks